# How do I compare two (not identical) tabs (or sheets) for differences in a specific column

Tags: google-sheets

I have two database dumps in Google sheets. They contain several thousand entries - many are identical, but not all. I now need to find all of those where a number in a specific column has increased by a certain number. The problem is that the rows not necessarily are the same, as entries in the database can have been deleted - and more been added, so rows do not add up.

I have tried various forms of 'if' and 'query'  - none that have brought me closer to a solution.

I'm thinking that I first need to compare the column where the unique id is to ensure that it is the right entry that is being compared.

I would like to completely automate this, but a semi-manual way of doing this could also be okay.

One solution for this could be to get Google to check the unique id's of the two tabs - and then display the content of a second column in the first tab only where the id's can be found in both tabs. 
I just cannot get Sheets to do this.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: To clarify:

The specific case is that I have two almost identical spreadsheets (tabs) - where I need to find the id's (column B) that are present in both tabs (identical) - and then display the value from a second column (column G) in the first tab for those id's.

Answer (score 3):

if I understood you right you can use filters for your task. For example

=FILTER(YourSheet1!B$2:B;YourSheet2!A$2:A=C2;YourSheet2!D$2:D=E2)

It will return you the line, where A$2:A == C2 and D$2:D == E2 from sheet two. So you can using filters choose data that has equal column values. If there exist copies it will return an error to the cell

Comment: Or you can just write script in google sheet that will take the content and make dictionary, where the key will be your id. Then refill the sheet and u will have no copies

Comment: Not sure this helps - the specific case is that I have two almost identical spreadsheets (tabs) - where I need to find the id's (column B) that are present in both tabs (identical)  - and then display the value from a second column (column G) in the first tab for those id's.

Comment: =FILTER(YourSheet2!G$2:G;YourSheet1!B$2:B=YourSheet2!B2)

Comment: If I'm right by this you are taking the data where your id's are the same

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution... A simple LOOKUP was what I needed:

=LOOKUP(B147,stats23Dec!B:B,stats23Dec!G:G)